# Calling an Azure AD secured Web API from Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a PoC application set, WebApi with a Angular (other or variant frontend), using Azure AD to authenticate my Federation users.

I've got the backend working fine, with authentication/MFA working as expected, and showing sign-in prompts.

[image]

[image]

I've got the Microsoft samples for Angular apps, but i'm struggling with implementation of said app, who do I use MSAL to get a token on the frontend, and have the backend accept said token and authenticate as that federated user?

This is my `app.module.ts` code from the sample, where

```
export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=[ ['https://localhost:5001/',['api://--------------/access_as_user']] , ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']] ];

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, HomeComponent, ProductComponent, ErrorComponent, ProductDetailComponent, TodoListComponent, UserDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{useHash:true}) ,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
        clientID: '-----------',
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
        validateAuthority: true,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
        cacheLocation : "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        popUp: !isIE,
        consentScopes: [ "user.read", "openid", "profile", "api://------------/access_as_user"],
        unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
        protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
        logger: loggerCallback,
        correlationId: '1234',
        piiLoggingEnabled: true
      }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [ProductService, TodoListService, HttpServiceHelper,
     {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `@azure/msal-angular` - frontend [NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) & `passport-azure-ad` - backend [NPM Package](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad)

And we get the token from the front end and validate that on the backend and get the email that is attached to that user and link it up with a user on our DB. But this only happens after the token has been validated on the backend by the Microsoft Graph.

So on our login page this is the code we import `import { BroadcastService, MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';`

In `NgOnInit` we have this

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:loginFailure', payload => {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      this.loaded = false;
    });
    this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:loginSuccess', payload => {
      console.log(payload);
      if (payload instanceof Object) {
        // Do something
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the code i have on the actual microsoft login button

```
microsoftLogin() {
    this.loaded = true;
    this.msal
      .loginPopup()
      .then(token => {
        this.microsoftAPILogin(token); // A call to send the token to our API
        this.loaded = false;
        this.loggedIn = true;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.loggedIn = false;
        this.loaded = false;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - when you say validate on the backend, is that purely just sending it to the backend, and having that re-check it?

Comment: Yeah so i have a node.js backend and i use `passport-azure-ad` for my backend validation, I'll add that to my answer now

Comment: Perfect - I've cracked my frontend, but I've got another issue - new Q raised - thanks

Comment: to me I followed the instruction at the link https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2019/08/adding-azure-active-directory-authentication-connect-angular-app-asp-net-core-web-api-using-msal/ and worked fine.

Comment: @Skel, can you please provide a sample code of this.microsoftAPILogin(token); and the backend code.